# How to signify to a client that an HTTP response is not complete

Tags: rest, http

I have a service that takes an incoming request and fulfills it asynchronously in the background (returning a `202 Accepted` status code to signify that it has begun processing). The client can check the status on that request by making GET requests to its resource.

Since that request is being processed in the background, at any time the client checks it might be incomplete (part of it may be missing and the process is not finished). Is there any RESTful way I can signify this to the client? Obviously I should provide `Cache-Control` headers that prevent the client from caching this response since it's not final. But what can I do to make the client know it should ask again later if it wants the latest information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to:

> The client can check the status on that request by making GET requests to its resource.

If *result* of the asynchronous background process is the creation of the the resource. This to me means that the resource should `404` until it's ready, at which point it should return `200`.

Based on this a client could find out that the process is not complete by checking the status code.

I would say that you probably also want to define a good response body (ideally using `application/problem+json`) so the client can find out *why* it's 404ing.

A second way to handle this is the way I usually prefer. I would create a separate 'status' resource. It's function is to just report on the status of the asynchronous operation, which may for example be `pending`, `complete` or `failed`. I'm not aware of any standard HTTP response formats for this, so you may need to define some JSON response body for this. A status resource should always just return `200 OK` since the 'status' can always be found.

Comment: Hi Evert, thanks for your response. In this case, the resource is slow to fully create (a few minutes), but I want the client to be able to retrieve whatever is done loading before it's finished. Can I return that partial content in a 404 response?

Comment: 404 is theoretically correct but a practically a bad idea because it is widely interpreted as an incorrect path. Support techs are guaranteed to go in the wrong direction.

Comment: @JohnWilliams i think that's a valid concern, and why a separate status endpoint may be better.

Comment: @Haf I guess it could be a bit surprising to have 'partial content' from a HTTP perspective. I think you just need to return `200 OK` then and have something in the body/headers indicating that there's more coming later.

Answer (score 0):

I use a 400 with an indication that the request is too early. Easy to wrap in an exponential back off retry mechanism.

There are others but not all clients can process, eg 423 locked.

Comment: 423 and 102 have specific meanings and they're not really applicable here. `102` in particular is not a final HTTP status code and implies the HTTP response is not complete and will be followed-up with a secondary status code.